# Using json to store values getting blocked when 2 or more user use the command at the same time

Tags: python, discord.py

I use json to store currency and I made a few games where people can earn currency by playing.

The problem is if 2 or more user use the command at the same time only one user will win/lose the currency in json. Is there a way to fix this?

This is an example code of the game that I made

`I changed my database to sqlite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **await** when you read from or write to file, else the bot will wait for the operation to finish.

The await wrapper makes your bot jump to another line of code and not wait for I/O processes.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Sorry I forgot to put await in ctx.send I edited it. Same problem.

Comment: This is a good guide for async programing in Python:
[link](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)

You need to 
`import asyncio

 async with aiofiles.open(file, "a") as f:`

Hope that helps mate!

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll just accept this as an answer! I fixed it by changing my database to sqlite. :)

Comment: Glad to help! Async is fun when you learn it. Its very powerful